# Pasting entire macros in a remote console shell

Tags: macros, clipboard

I am configuring a server using its remote console (which is **not** SSH, as I haven't installed the OS yet).

Unfortunately after a long series of driver failures I end up repeating typing the following task from Rescue system

```
mount /dev/sda3 /mnt
mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/boot/efi
mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev
mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc
mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys
chroot /mnt
```

I am really tired about typing them!! If it was an SSH console I could easily paste them from my clipboard, but in a pre-OS environment I need to use HP's embedded Remote Console.

Is there any way from Windows I can emulate keystrokes when pasting a long blob of text I can copy to clipboard?

Comment: If I understand your issue, I would consider creating a bind using AutoHotKey to send the keystrokes.

Comment: Sounds cool...I didn't know about the existence of AutoHotkey